# Lib to build an admin-page from a Database schema?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, admin

I'm using ASP.Net and NHibernate to build a website. Now, I need to add some sort of administration functionality, and came to think of an old django tutorial I once ran through. Here the admin page was build for me, and I could customize it as I liked.

I see no reason that I couldn't accomplish the same, somehow, in ASP.Net, when I got my NHibernate schemas, thus reducing all the boilerplate admin-code I need to do. Are there any libs out there, that you think will fill my needs somehow?

Thanks in advance :)
- cwap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) is good. It allows you to generate ASP.NET admin pages based on your data classes.

A free alternative is [mygeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx)

Comment: Don't really think any of those are what I really need :) But thanks for trying. Gonna mark this as accepted, as I guess it's the closed i'll get to what I want :)